# Java Scanner ListArray ParseInt Попробовал справиться с закрытием потока System.in через строковые методы. Получил исключение

Tags: java, парсер, arraylist

Ввод:

`-574 -484 444 -217 978 -370 269 -9 189`

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String sc = input.nextLine();
String[] numbers = sc.split(" ");
input.close();
List result = new ArrayList<>();
for (int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++) {
    String item = numbers[x];
    if (result.contains(item)) {
        continue;
    }
    result.add(item);
}
int[] vals = new int[result.size()];
for(int x = 0; x<result.size(); x++) {
    vals[x] = Integer.parseInt(result.get(x));
}
System.out.println(vals);
```

Результат меня удивил ... ( ожидал, что заберёт строку, распарсит в целые и выдаст в массиве ...  -574 -484 444 -217 978 -370 269 -9 189
[I@37bba400

Comment: Нужно не удивляться, а указывать проблему/сообщение об ошибке или исключение в тексте вопроса.  Во-первых, код не компилируется, так как список `result` не типизирован и возникает ошибка: `error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to String: vals[x] = Integer.parseInt(result.get(x));`  Если проблема в том, что вместо массива выводится `[I@37bba400`, то это известный факт, для печати содержимого следует использовать `Arrays.toString(vals)`

Comment: Простите. Не указал,, что Я extremlyNew в Java. Решаю учебную задачу -  Перейдите в класс MaxMethod и реализуйте метод max. Правильная реализация должна получить массив значений типа int и вернуть его максимальное значение. Подробности: Входной массив гарантированно не будет пустым или null. Метод max не должен изменять массив. Входной массив может содержать любое значение типа int от Integer.MIN_VALUE до Integer.MAX_VALUE. Проверка  - Maven поект autotest ) .

Comment: В ListArray и   String sc = input.nextLine(); String[] numbers = sc.split(" "); пошел - как в действенный автоматизированный способ закрытия потока Input.Stream.

Comment: package com.epam.rd.autotasks.max;

public class MaxMethod {
    public static int max(int[] values) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос очень неясен, нужно детально описывать проблему и прикладывать ошибку. Попробую раскрыть из того что видно.

1. `List result = new ArrayList<>();` - это нетипизированный (raw-тип) список, поэтому result.get() вернёт Object, поэтому компилятор выдаст ошибку на `Integer.parseInt(result.get(x))`. Наилучший вариант здесь - сделать типизацию:
   `List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();`
2. `System.out.println(vals)` выдаёт дефолтное строковое представление массива. Дефолтным строковым представлением массива является вот эта слабочитаемая абракадабра [I@37bba400, которая обозначает что это массив целых с хешем равным 0x37bba400; Для нормального представления в строке стоило бы использовать утилитный метод Arrays.toString: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vals));`
3. Это не ошибка, но я бы советовал вместо явного закрытия стрима вызовом close(), использовать try-with-resources.
   Итого, после всех правок, код должен выглядеть как-то так:

```
        try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            String sc = input.nextLine();
            String[] numbers = sc.split(" ");

            List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++) {
                String item = numbers[x];
                if (result.contains(item)) {
                    continue;
                }
                result.add(item);
            }
            int[] vals = new int[result.size()];
            for (int x = 0; x < result.size(); x++) {
                vals[x] = Integer.parseInt(result.get(x));
            }
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vals));
        }
```

Для введённой строки `-574 -484 444 -217 978 -370 269 -9 189` вывод будет следующий:

`[-574, -484, 444, -217, 978, -370, 269, -9, 189]`

Comment: БЛАГОДАРЮ ВАС !

Comment: Решаю учебную задачу - Перейдите в класс MaxMethod и реализуйте метод max. Правильная реализация должна получить массив значений типа int и вернуть его максимальное значение. Подробности: Входной массив гарантированно не будет пустым или null. Метод max не должен изменять массив. Входной массив может содержать любое значение типа int от Integer.MIN_VALUE до Integer.MAX_VALUE. Проверка - Maven поект autotest ) В ListArray и String sc = input.nextLine(); String[] numbers = sc.split(" "); пошел - как в действенный автоматизированный способ закрытия потока Input.Stream.

Comment: О стриме - отдельно. Варианты работать сразу с Integer проваливались, поскольку методы HasNextInt() в while цикле не выдавали false, когда добегали до конца ввода и получался вечный цикл. Некоторые коллеги пошли путём не совсем, на мой взгляд, не корректным, они стали просто ограничивать размер массива некими значениями типа if ( arrays.size() == 10 ) break;